# how to handle the response from the payment gateway, if our server goes down

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing

For example in paypal when completed the payment, the response is going to response.php at that time if our server goes down. how to handle this situation and what need to be done.

In other payment gateway also how to handle the situation when our server goes down while the response is receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're referring to PayPal IPN data, this is reattempted up to 16 times over several days if initial delivery was not successful.
Thus, if your server is unable to acknowledge the data with a HTTP/1.1 200 OK response, PayPal will mark the IPN data as not having been delivered, and will start re-trying 5 minutes after the initial attempt, then 10 minutes, 20, 30, et cetera.